# How do I repeat what I am putting in the Enter Parameter Box in an Access Report?

Tags: ms-access, user-input

I have a report that contains 3 subreports that are from queries. Each query requires the user to input the date as mmyyyy. When I run the report I have to put in the same date 3 times. Is there a way to input the date once and have it input for all 3 queries? The 3 queries each get information from a fourth query by the date and group by different columns. I would rather not have to use a macro or anything too complicated, I'm still new at this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the simplest method is probably to set a [TempVar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.tempvar?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361).

This you can include in your queries to filter on the date.

Comment: Can I not set up a form or something for user input? I really don't want to use a macro for this.

Comment: Yes, but that will require more code. Code to set a `TempVar` is nearly nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, I ended up doing what this person did and got the result I wanted: [Single Parameter Multiple Queries in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26596170/single-parameter-multiple-queries-in-ms-access?rq=1)